# How can i parse this json file without displaying the /n and br tags?

Tags: objective-c, json

This is the json file:

```
[{"normal":"1","ID":"67216","category_id":"1","MainHeadline":"Susuwe Lodge am Kwando abgebrannt","ImagePath":"http:\/\/nte.nmh.com.na\/FINALSERVER\/PROCESSEDIMAGE\/030815\/thumb\/0308-3-1-SUSUWE%20(2).JPG","Logo":"http:\/\/nte.nmh.com.na\/MyInfo\/Logos\/AZ_Logo.png","FullStory":"Von Dirk Heinrich, Kongola\\n\u00e2\u0080\u009eIch habe nur noch meinen Personalausweis retten k\u00c3\u00b6nnen, ansonsten ist alles in meiner Unterkunft verbrannt, mein Bett, mein Schrank, alles\u00e2\u0080\u009d, sagte einer der Angestellten der Susuwe Island Lodge,Lukas Ndunda, der zusammen mit Sebastian Moses versucht hatte, am Sonntagnachmittag bei starken Wind das Feuer von der Lodge abzuwenden.\u00e2\u0080\u009c Als das Hauptgeb\u00c3\u00a4ude brannte, sind Moses und ich ins Wasser gesprungen und die 15 bis 20 Meter zum gegen\u00c3\u00bcberliegenden Ufer geschwommen, um uns zu retten\u00e2\u0080\u009d, erz\u00c3\u00a4hlte Ndunda.<br \/>\u00e2\u0080\u009eDie Lodge ist zum gr\u00c3\u00b6\u00c3\u009ften Teil zerst\u00c3\u00b6rt. Binnen einer Stunde war alles vorbei. Wir hatten die Lodge f\u00c3\u00bcr zwei Millionen Namibia-Dollar renoviert und im vergangenen Jahr im Juli wieder er\u00c3\u00b6ffnet. Die Flammen vernichteten das Hauptgeb\u00c3\u00a4ude, drei der sechs Bungalows, alle Unterk\u00c3\u00bcnfte der Angestellten und einen der Wassertanks\u00e2\u0080\u009d, teilte Reinhardt K\u00c3\u00bcsters mit. Er ist der Eigent\u00c3\u00bcmer der Caprivi Lodges, Lianshulu und Susuwe, zusammen mit zwei holl\u00c3\u00a4ndischen Partnern. Besch\u00c3\u00a4digt wurden zudem die Werkstatt und die W\u00c3\u00a4scherei sowie das Geb\u00c3\u00a4ude, in dem ein Generator untergebracht ist. Auch eines der Boote, mit dem Touristen zur Lodge auf der Insel gebracht werden und welches zu Bootsfahrten auf dem Kwando genutzt wird, wurde Opfer der Flammen. Nicht nur die Geb\u00c3\u00a4ude sondern auch die gesamte Inneneinrichtung und Ausr\u00c3\u00bcstung wurden zerst\u00c3\u00b6rt, ebenso die Vorr\u00c3\u00a4te und zahlreiche riesige B\u00c3\u00a4ume, unter denen die Geb\u00c3\u00a4ude standen.<br \/>\u00e2\u0080\u009eWir hatten Gl\u00c3\u00bcck in dem Inferno. Ich habe einige kleinere Verbrennungen erlitten, aber ansonsten ist niemandem etwas passiert\u00e2\u0080\u009d, sagte Moses. K\u00c3\u00bcsters war froh, dass zu dem Zeitpunkt am vergangenen Sonntagnachmittag keine G\u00c3\u00a4ste in der Lodge waren. Gestern Morgen rauchten noch zahlreiche Baumst\u00c3\u00a4mme und das Gel\u00c3\u00a4nde um die Lodge war schwarz und kahl.<br \/>\u00e2\u0080\u009eDas Feuer wurde von irgendjemandem im kommunalen Hegegebiet Mayuni entfacht. Entweder hat jemand bei dem starken Wind, der die letzten Tage wehte, das Veld absichtlich in Brand gesteckt oder jemand hat beim Brandroden nicht aufgepasst. Das Feuer wurde im trockenen Gras von einem starken Ostwind nach Westen getrieben\u00e2\u0080\u009d, sagte K\u00c3\u00bcsters. Selbst der Kwando konnte die Flammen nicht aufhalten. Das Feuer sprang \u00c3\u00bcber den Fluss und wurde weiter nach Westen getrieben. Es \u00c3\u00bcberquerte verschiedene Wasserl\u00c3\u00a4ufe in dem weitverzweigten Gebiet des Kwando und erreichte schlie\u00c3\u009flich die Susuwe Island Lodge. Das zur Hilfe gerufene Personal der Lianshulu Lodge konnte nicht mehr helfen, da das Hauptgeb\u00c3\u00a4ude bereits in Flammen stand, als sie am Westufer im Bwabwata-Nationalpark, Bereich Mudumu-Nationalpark, ankamen. Neben drei Bungalows blieb auch das Haus des Managers von den Flammen unversehrt.<br \/>Wie hoch der Schaden ist, konnte noch nicht festgestellt werden, auch nicht was nun geschehen soll. Vor kurzem wurde in der N\u00c3\u00a4he der Lianshulu Lodge im Mudumu-Nationalpark der namibische Reisef\u00c3\u00bchrer Andi Maier ermordet. Die K\u00c3\u00bcsters k\u00c3\u00bcmmerten sich als Erste um die Freundin des Ermordeten.<br \/>","Edition":"Allgemeine Zeitung","Story":"Von Dirk Heinrich, Kongola\u00e2\u0080\u009e \\\\n Ich habe nur noch meinen Personalausweis retten k\u00c3\u00b6nnen, ansonsten ist alles in meiner Unterkunft verbrannt, mein Bett, mein Schrank, alles\u00e2\u0080\u009d, sagte einer der Angestellten d...d...","ImageCaption":"Nur Schutt und Asche sind vom Hauptgeb\u00c3\u00a4ude \u00c3\u00bcbrig geblieben, in dem die G\u00c3\u00a4ste sich ausruhen","PublishDate":"2015-08-04T18:17:00","Author":"Eberhard Hofmann"},
```

the url of this file is:http://app.nmh.com.na/generator/getStories.php?CategoryID=1

When i parse it,the app displays the /n and br tags instead of just adding a line beak.Dos anyone know how i can fix this..Please assist..

Comment: how are you parsing it?  and into what are you displaying it (a UITextView or something else?)?

Comment: check this  [NSDictionary+JSON](https://github.com/robertodias180/RDCategories/blob/master/RDCategories/Source/NSDictionary/NSDictionary%2BJSON.h)

Comment: I am using NSDictionary and parsing the url of the json file content and displaying the content into a uilabel.Please try parsing the url i posted and see if you guys also get break tags displaying,,i am really stuck.I have also serialized the json.